# Attempt to authenticate with the salt master failed

Tags: virtual-machine, salt-stack

Can I use salt-master in VM(Ubuntu) control salt-minion in VM(Ubuntu) on different computers?

Because when I try to set public ip in /etc/salt/minion and run salt-minion & salt-master, minion always says '[ERROR]Attempt to authenticate with the salt master failed'

Comment: Have you checked with the command `salt-key -L`,whether the key of the minion has been listed? If yes, have you accepted it? Use  `salt-key -A` to accept all the unaccepted keys and `salt-key -a <minion_id>` to accept a specific key referenced by the minion id.

Comment: I have checked command salt-key,but i cant see any key in list...so i ask this question here...

Comment: Try to run the minion in debug mode using `salt-minion -l debug` and please post the log, it will be beneficial in rectifying why the key isn't being listed with the master.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've set the public IP in /etc/salt/minion (and I'm assuming you've set that on the "master: " line, and uncommented that line), and that you've noted the master can't see the minion's key when running `salt-key -A`, it's likely that something is interrupting communications between the minion and the salt master.

I'd first check the minion can ping the master, and then do a `nc -v X.X.X.X 4505` to see if you get tcp connection through.

It's possible you'll need to refer to http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/firewall.html to make firewall changes to permit the communication.